# A question on the RMS of a "Gaussian" Distribution

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

We suppose to have this "gaussian" distribution:

[image]

with $mean=1217.60 [ch]$;
and $RMS=143.65 [ch]$;

where [ch] is channel.

The question is, the error over the mean is: $\pm \sqrt{RMS}$? And why?

Comment: what makes you think ^^that^^ is a Gaussian, and how did you get an RMS of 143-ish?

Comment: This is definitely not a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Did you mean log-Gaussian, inverse-Gaussian, skew-Gaussian? Because as others have noted, it's not a "vanilla" Gaussian.

Comment: We suppose that the distribution that i mentioned is a real gaussian (i know, i needed to specifify this). 

The squared root of RMS is the error of the mean?

Comment: Any chance you could replace the figure with one that has abscissa from channel 500 through channel 2500? It would even more clearly show that the peak is **not** Gaussian.

Comment: @EdV I know that it is not a Gaussian. I mean, if we suppose that the distribution is a gaussian, we can say that the error's mean is the root square of RMS?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to clarify this. In short: **no**, the measurement error in the population mean is not the population RMS. For example, if you measure men's heights, the RMS is whatever it is, but with accurate enough equipment (or large enough sample) you can make the measurement error in the mean as small as you like. (I'd have made this an answer, but I'm still not 100% sure I know what you're asking.)

Comment: Can you say where the RMS value came from? Was it computed from the full width at half maximum (FWHM) height? In particular, would 143.65 be from dividing the estimated FWHM by about 2.355? If so, then that would mean that the RMS estimate is the assumed standard deviation of the assumed Gaussian shape. But, of course, the peak is not Gaussian, as you confirmed.

Comment: @EdV No, i don't know how it comes from and i dont know how it is calculated. For this reason i have posted this question. So if it is the standard deviation the error is 2.355*RMS ?

Comment: @J.G. And what do you think about the last reply of Ed V ?

Comment: I repeat my point that "the error on the mean" is defined to be something very different from the population standard deviation. (Feel however you like about that, but my example illustrates why two different concepts each warrant a label.)

Comment: As per @J.G., I would not call the 143.65 “an error on the mean”. For a Gaussian, FWHM = 2 $\sigma (2log2)^{1/2}$, which is approximately 2.355 $\sigma$. But you do not have a Gaussian peak shape so that equation is inapplicable. Knowing nothing more of the peak shape, you can get an empirical FWHM and leave it at that. So I agree with J.G. The FWHM, or something proportional to it, is not the error on the mean. It is just a measure of peak width.